# PHP DateTime accepting invalid date

Tags: php, datetime, date

I'm having trouble using the PHP `DateTime` class, and more specifically the `DateTime::createFromFormat()`.

I get a date from a string, then try to instanciate a DateTime object, using `DateTime::createFromFormat()`. But, when I give this function a date that cannot exist, it is still working, returning me a valid `DateTime` object, with a valid date, **which isn't the date I gave it**.

### Code example :

```
$badDate = '2010-13-03';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $badDate);

var_dump($date);

/*
object(DateTime)#284 (3) {
["date"]=>
string(19) "2011-01-03 10:01:20"
["timezone_type"]=>
int(3)
["timezone"]=>
string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
*/
```

Any ideas? I really need a way to check date validity.

Thank you.

### Edit:

I just found why, see my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`DateTime::createFromFormat` doesn't throw exception/return false when the given date is impossible. It try to guess the expected date.

If you give it `'2010-01-32'` (as in Januar, 32th), it will return a `DateTime` object containing Februar, 1st (Januar 31th + 1 day). Must be logical... in some weird twisted way.

To check the validity, you must check the `DateTime::getLastErrors()` which contains warning, like for my case :

```
array(4) {
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(1) {
    [10]=>
    string(27) "The parsed date was invalid"
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

This behavior seems to come from the UNIX timestamp which PHP calculate, based on the year, month and date you give it (even if the date is invalid).

Comment: "Must be logical... in some weird twisted way." ==> Oh, we see that a lot in PHP.

Comment: Anyone reading this remember to check for both warnings AND errors, especially if you write your own isValidDate function to wrap around this.

Answer (score 15):

I found example where validation based on `DateTime::getLastErrors()` will fail, so better solution would be to compare inputed date with generated date.

### Code:

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $dt && $dt->format($format) == $date;
}
```

### Use example:

```
var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-28')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-30')); # false

# you can validate and date/time format
var_dump(validateDate('14:50', 'H:i')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('14:99', 'H:i')); # false

# this is the example where validation with `DateTime::getLastErrors()` will fail
var_dump(validateDate('Tue, 28 Feb 2012 12:12:12 +0200', DateTime::RSS)); # true
var_dump(validateDate('Tue, 27 Feb 2012 12:12:12 +0200', DateTime::RSS)); # false
```

Comment: ouch, nice catch. What version of PHP are you using for this test? Maybe this was fixed along the way?

Comment: @ClementHerreman: this result is on all PHP version that support `DateTime::createFromFormat`, that is all above php >= 5.3.0. [See it in action here](http://3v4l.org/n2iag). I never said that `DateTime::getLastErrors()` should report warning or error in this case, probably this works as intended (ignoring string days), but IMO, if we are doing validation function, it should matter, because `27 Feb 2012` is not `Tuesday`, it is `Monday`.

Comment: In this example `DateTime::getLastErrors()` reports error only in case if textual day cannot be found or it is invalid, [see](http://3v4l.org/Wh0MF).

Comment: Much nicer solution, as this should handle both errors and warnings. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

You have to make use of `DateTime::getLastErrors()` which will contain the error `The parsed date was invalid`.

```
$badDate = '2010-13-03';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $badDate);
if( DateTime::getLastErrors()['warning_count'] > 0 ){
 //not a correct date
}else{
 //correct date
 print $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Look for [`checkdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) function at php documentation. It will help you :)

Comment: This should have been the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that :

```
DateTime::getLastErrors()
```

Answer (score -1):

change

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $badDate);
```

into

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-d-m', $badDate);
```

Your **given format is wrong**, you properly mixed up days and months...

To understand what is behind the magical calculation of dates read this very very [good article by Derick Rethans](http://derickrethans.nl/obtaining-the-next-month-in-php.html) and all comments ;)

Comment: The format isn't wrong, it really is `Y-m-d', I want to ensure that date validity is checked.

Comment: But when `m` is the second part and you pass `13`: its calculated as January in the next year. Everything is fine here! This is the way PHP calculates with overlapping numbers on dates.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I just discovered, but 2 questions rise : 1. where the hell is it documented ? 2. Am I the only that doesn't find this behavior logical/expectable ?

Comment: I added a link to an article.

Comment: Nice article, but maybe you should also edit your answer about me using a bad format =).